# Linear Algebra Proof $AB=0 \Longrightarrow \det(A)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Two squared matrices $A$ and $B$, with $B\neq0$, give $AB=0$. Prove that $\det(A)=0$.

After trying with some examples, I believe that $A$ needs to have lines that are equal or can be made equal by scalar multiplication, B needs to have columns that are equal or can be made equal by scalar multiplication, like
$$ A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 \\
        2 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$ B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 4 \\
        -1 & -2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

which would mean that $\det(A)=0$ and $\det(B)=0$.
But this is still far from being a proof of anything. Am I on the right track? What would be my next step?

Comment: Do you know that det$(AB)=$det$(A)$det$(B)$.

Comment: I don't know whether this helps, but $\det(0)=0$ and $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. So $\det(A)\det(B)=0$, hence $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(B)=0$. Unfortunately, $B \neq 0$ doesn't imply $\det(B)\neq0$

Comment: Let $b$ be any nonzero column of $B$. Then $AB = 0$ implies $Ab = 0$. What does this tell you about $A$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By  contradiction:  suppose $\det A \ne 0$, than $A$ is invertible and, left multiplying $AB=0$ by  $A^{-1}$, we have:
$$
A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}\cdot 0 \iff (A^{-1}A)B=0 \iff I B= 0 \iff B=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $AB=0$ then $Ab_i=0$ $\forall 1\leq i\leq n$ (where $b_i$ denotes the i-th column of B. Let $b_j$ be any non-zero column of B then we have:
$Ab_j=0$ which means that $b_j$ is an eigenvector of A with corresponding eigenvalue 0. Since 0 is an eigenvalue of A then $det(A)=0$

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that B was a sqaure matrix.

Comment: Forget I said anything

Comment: You should be able to delete your answer.

Comment: Your argument works if you let $b$ be any nonzero column of $B$. Then $b$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue zero.

Comment: So if $AB=0$ then $ Ab_i=0  \forall  i $ where $b_i$ is the i-th column of B.
Then B is made of eigenvectors that correspond to the eigenvalue 0. Is this better?

Comment: Some of the columns of $B$ may be zero, so those columns won't count as eigenvectors. However, $B$ is nonzero, so at least one of its columns must be nonzero, and that column is an eigenvector which corresponds to the eigenvalue zero.